# Fix layout of plot(fevd()) function

Tags: r, variables, plot, var

I am trying to plot FEVD (forecast error variance decomposition) for my VAR analysis. As you can see on the image, the legend screws up the graph and information. as this is an automatically created legend, I don’t know how to reposition it. I do not know much yet about plotting in R.

The only code i use to get this is :

```
library(vars)
var <- VAR(varTable2 , p=4 , type = "both")
plot(fevd(var, n.ahead = 10 ))
```

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legends do not resize well in R. You have to set your plotting window first and then chart your data. 
Here's how to do it in Windows. `win.graph` opens a blank plotting window of the specified width. In Unix/Linux, you should look at `X11()` and in Mac, at `quartz()`. You might also consider shorter variable names.

```
library(vars)
data(Canada)
colnames(Canada) <-c("Long column name1","Long column name2","Long column name3","Long column name4")
var <- VAR(Canada , p=4 , type = "both")
win.graph(width=13,height=8)
plot(fevd(var, n.ahead = 10 ))
```

[image]